# Updating 2nd SELECT element based on value in 1st SELECT element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bit of HTML / Javascript which will change the value of Select Menu B based on the value of the selection of Select Menu A.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#name-first").change(function() {
        $("#name-second")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p>First Name: 
    <select id="name-first">
        <option value="1">UK</option>
        <option value="2">US</option>
        <option value="3">France</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p>Surname: 
    <select id="name-second">
        <option value="1">UK</option>
        <option value="2">US</option>
        <option value="3">France</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

That is working, but I've realised that I need to change it so that jQuery updates the "name-second" SELECT menu based on the value of the text between the option tags, rather than the value of the option itself.

e.g. for this sample, the option values are different, but the text between the option tags is the same. So if a user selected e.g. US on the "name-first" select, the "name-second" will update to show the "US" option as selected.

```
<p>First Name: 
    <select id="name-first">
        <option value="234">UK</option>
        <option value="15">US</option>
        <option value="12">France</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p>Surname: 
    <select id="name-second">
        <option value="562">UK</option>
        <option value="10">US</option>
        <option value="6">France</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

I wondered if it would be a big change to the jQuery function to be able to adapt to that slightly different requirement, and if anyone might be able to help me with the revision please?

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In the link you provided they want to load results into the 2nd dropdown based on what's selected in the first dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery selector `:contains()` to match the text inside your options:

```
$("#name-second option:contains('" + $("#name-first option:selected").text() + "')").prop('selected', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DVszJ/

Comment: No problem. Many people don't know about `:contains()`. It's very useful at times.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for changing second select box by index:

```
$("#name-first").change(function() {
    $("#name-second").prop('selectedIndex', $(this).prop('selectedIndex'));
});
```

use this code for changing second select box by value:

```
$("#name-first").change(function() {
    $("#name-second").val($(this).val());
});
```

use this code for changing second select box by text:

```
    $(function() {
     $("#name-first").change(function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        var a = $that.find('option:selected').text();
        $('#name-second option').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.text() === a){
                $('#name-second').prop('selectedIndex', $this.index());
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

see this updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/x2pL3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#name-first").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "15"){
    $("#name-second").val("10");
  }
});
```